# Enhance picture taking HTML5 by overriding default camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, camera, overriding

I'm using the input with source from camera in a HTML5 web application such as :

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

But I was wondering if there's a way (ie with JQuery Mobile) to improve the picture taking process. For instance, put a layer over the camera view which detects if the point of view is optimal, if there's no obstacle between the subject of the picture and the smartphone and so on.

I'm not talking about the difficulty to code such as algorithms, but I'm wondering if it's possible to override "system functionnalities" such as the camera only with Javascript and enhance the simple camera view (with just the "take picture" button and the basic functionnalities).

My first though is no, it would require an mobile app (not a web app) which have the required rights to take a picture. I also think that it would be a security leak to allow Javascript to interact and alter system functionnalities.

But I'm not 100% sure, could someone confirm please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can override system functionalities, however you can get your camera to show in a canvas element which can allow you to do various "canvassey" things such as streaming the image to the server or making it greyscale etc.

This is just taking some code I was messing around with:

HTML

```
<video id="myvideo" controls></video>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var isStreaming = false,
   video = $('#myvideo')[0],
   canvas = $('#mycanvas')[0],
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
   w = 800,
   h = 400;
   navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

$(window).load(function() {
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
            video.src = src
            video.play();               

        }, function(error) {
            alert('Error: ' + error);
            return;
        });
    } else {
      alert('not supported in your browser');
    }
});

video.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
   if (!isStreaming) {
        // videoWidth isn't always set correctly in all browsers
        if (video.videoWidth > 0) h = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / w);
        canvas.setAttribute('width', w);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', h);

        // Reverse the canvas image
        //ctx.translate(w, 0);
        //ctx.scale(-1, 1);         

        isStreaming = true;
   }
}, false);

video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    // Every 33 milliseconds copy the video image to the canvas
    setInterval(function() {
        if (video.paused || video.ended) return;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);       
   }, 33);
}, false);
```

This simply just streams a camera into a canvas. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Very nice !

I still have a question, is it possible to do some real-time capture and process it in live ? For instance, with such a mechanism, I'd like to be able to retrieve the current view of the camera (such as when you're taking a picture) even when the photo isn't already taken and apply an algorithm to detect if there's an obstacle in the view. 

The problem would be to get the "passive" view of the camera and I don't know if it's possible with the video tag (which is possible with native functionnalities on iOS and Android)

Comment: That would require some image processing on the canvas I guess to detect pixel colours near one another, ratios, etc. or something? It could probably be done, but might be a few thousand lines of code :P (and could potentially eat your processor for breakfast in doing so)

Comment: Something that potentially could be of use: https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/

Comment: Yep i'm afraid it would be a heavy process. The idea would be to take a "snap" each X miliseconds and check if there's an obstacle or not, instead of checking at each frame.

The lib you gave in the link seems to be really usefull, I'll dig it. 

I also found it (to capture the "passive image" of a camera) : 
http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

Btw thanks for your help, you've been really helpful :)

Comment: No problem. I put a lot of research into trying to stream a webcam with HTML5 and Web Sockets a few months back, I got as far as doing some of this stuff, but trying to throw a whole image to a server every 33 milliseconds?... made my web application sad... x_x